# In jQuery Validate plugin, how to only validate required fields for being empty, (without syntax validation)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Since the real validation should, and is happening server-side, I would like jQuery only to validate if required fields are not empty. So I've got these defaults:

```
  jQuery.validator.setDefaults({ 
    rules: {
      required: true,
      email: false // Experimental, does nothing?
    }
  });
```

The problem is that jQuery validation plugin still performs other checks (like email syntax), which differ from server-side implementations. How to turn them off?

As far as I got their [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) setting properties like: `rules` > `email` or `rules` > `url` to **false** should do the trick... But apparently it doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is **not implemented** in the latest version at the moment of writing (1.13.1) as was stated by Sparky in his answer, I've come up with a few lines of code to do this outside documented plugin functionality. Sharing:

```
jQuery.validator.methods.email = function(){return true;}
jQuery.validator.methods.url = function(){return true;}
// Etc for each method you wish to disable
```

What this code does is that it replaces original validation methods with a custom function which always returns **`true`**. This way HTML5 attributes may be kept intact, and there is no need for assigning rules for each individual field in the jQuery Validate plugin settings.

These custom functions can be easily extended so the original validation method (for ex. stored in a variable) can be called optionally if you still need it.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The object literal inside your `.setDefaults()` method is meaningless to this plugin...

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({ 
    rules: {
        required: true,
        email: false // Experimental, does nothing?
    }
});
```

You can **only** assign rules to individual fields when using the `rules` option...

```
rules: {
    myFieldName: { // <- this was missing
        required: true
    }
}
```

> `email: false` // Experimental, does nothing?

I'm not really sure what you think `email: false` is supposed to do.

- `email: true` means the field will get evaluated as a valid email address
- `email: false` does nothing because it's practically the same as leaving out the `email` rule here.  Otherwise, it could only [disable the `email` rule if it's set with an inline attribute](http://jsfiddle.net/yyvcnph4/).

Regardless, you cannot use `.setDefaults()` to over ride any rules that have already been put in place with `.validate()`.  If you are trying to "remove" a jQuery Validate rule already put in place by any other means, you can use [the `.rules('remove')` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/).

However, I am questioning your whole approach.  Why would you assign the `email` rule in the first place, only to remove it later.  *In your case, not enough information or code is shown to know what you're doing or what else is broken.*

---

**EDIT**:

Through comments, it is learned that the `email` rule is being used because the field has the HTML 5 attribute `type="email"`, which the plugin automatically picks up and assigns the `email` rule.

If you do not want the `email` rule, then you cannot use a `type="email"` field.  Use `type="text"` and avoid other HTML 5 validation attributes.

Comment: Re-comment, sorry:
Are you saying that it's not possible to turn off all validation rules except `required` (without having to do this for each individual field)? Answering your question about my approach. I'm not assigning any rules, this happens by default and I'm trying to prevent it. I only need to check if required fields are empty or not. No I don't want the HTML5 validation. Also I know that jQuery Validate plugin has nothing to do with server-side validation (I've built it), thank you. All I want is jQuery validation plugin to check ONLY if the required fields are empty. Nothing else.

Comment: @Alph.Dev, **how can any of this be happening by default?**  Something is telling the plugin to assign these rules in the first place, and that's the part totally left out of your question.

Comment: There is nothing left out. I have multiple forms site wide. In JS only the code posted in the question description + this line after that: `$('form').validate();`.

Comment: @Alph.Dev, you've left out the relevant HTML.  Please explain how the jQuery Validate plugin can possible know to assign the `email` rule to your field?

Comment: @Alph.Dev, probably should have mentioned you are using HTML 5 attributes to assign the jQuery Validate rules.  Don't use the HTML 5 attributes is the answer.  `type="text"`.

Comment: Quote @Alph.Dev:  *"Are you saying that it's not possible to turn off all validation rules except required (without having to do this for each individual field)?"* ~ Exactly.  There are lots of ways to assign rules, however, when using the `rules` option, you must explicitly assign each rule to the field's `name`.  It's better to assign the correct rules in the first place, rather than allow HTML 5 attributes to set rules and try to remove some of these later.  There is no advantage to these HTML 5 attributes if you're using the jQuery Validate plugin.